# Процесс заказа в ubercart глючит

Tags: drupal

помогите пожалуйста советом

при клике на кнопку "в корзину" у некоторых товаров на экран выводится следующее

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/site_mstore\/drupal7_mstore\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"mstore","theme_token":"wSmz3u_e17EHMqoVuq_DOAr5oqq6fUL5w-UrLIeNqaQ"},"colorbox":{"opacity":"0.85","current":"{current} \u0438\u0437 {total}","previous":"\u00ab \u041f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u044b\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0438\u0439","next":"\u0421\u043b\u0435\u0434\u0443\u044e\u0449\u0438\u0439 \u00bb","close":"\u0417\u0430\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c","maxWidth":"98%","maxHeight":"98%","fixed":true}},"merge":true}]
```

где искать проблему даже не представляю. поскажите пожалуйста

а некоторые товары без подобных проблем отправляются в корзину

при этом пробовал удалить модуль ubercart и установить его заново. так же пробовал отключить все, написанные мной яваскрипты.не моиогло